# Cross Correlation Between Input-Output Sine Waves

Tags: correlation

I am writing an algorithm to estimate the frequency transfer function of the system. For this, I want to use the Cross-correlation Between Input-Output Sine Waves method. There are a few things I don't understand about method:
I - What does capital N mean?
II - Is and Ic scalar or vector(depend on N)?
These are my thoughts : 
I - N represents the number of outputs I collected for a specific w value with a sampling periode.
II - Scalar.
Could you help?
[image: imgg]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

These formulas are [discrete fourier transform](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Discrete_Fourier_transform).

It's very standard procedure when you analyze wave-alike processes. What it does it transforms the signal from the time-space to the frequencies-space. The idea is that you take sin-wave with specific frequency, multiply it by signal and if the value is big then you have something similar to the wave of this frequency.

$\frac{1}{NT}$ term is just overall time of the sequence (N samples with length T)

The $I_{s}$ and $I_{c}$ is amplitude(intensity) for the sin and cos, respectively. You get them for the specific frequency $\omega$ and it's a single number for each. From this you can get full amplitude (G) and phase $\phi$. Why do you need phase? Because it's important - if you have two waves with similar frequency and $\phi = \pi$, then they would cancel each other, and if they have same phase, they would double.

Comment: Thank you for your helpful answer. Can you give an example for N and T for better understanding? For example, What can we say for N and T if I collect samples for y = sin (pi * t) with a sampling period of 0.1 seconds from 0 to 3 seconds?

Comment: Than you would have N = 30 samples, T=0.1 second.

Comment: Since the upper limit of the summation must be an integer (NT = 30 * 0.1 = 3), I should select the product of N and T to be an integer right?

Comment: Not really, what they mean by this notation I believe is that you iteratate from 0 till NT with step T.
I.e. for N=30 and T = 0.1 it would be k = 0.1, 0.2, 0.3 ... 3.

Comment: But it could be from 0 to 2.5 with step 0.1 and then k = 0.1, 0.2, 0.3, ... 2.5

Comment: I am sorry this is my mistake. Then my last question is:
for N = 3 and T = 0.1 sec. (NT = 0.3)
For example, the output values are y = [ 0.4 ,0.5, 0.6 ].
In this case, Is = (1 / 0.3) * (0.4 * sin (w * 0.1) + 0.5 * sin (w * 0.2) + 0.6 * sin (w * 0.3))?

Comment: OR  Is = (1 / 0.3) * (0.4 * sin (w * 0) + 0.5 * sin (w * 1) + 0.6 * sin (w * 2))?

Comment: The first one, with 0.1, 0.2

Comment: You really saved my life, thank you!